# MariaDB ibdata1 file cannot be written

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariasql

I am using MariaDB for windows.
It is stange, all worked before I changed the root-password with the commands

```
USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

and

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');
```

(password is just a fake)

I somehow cannot start the database via the command:

```
bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=my.ini --standalone --console
```

What I've already tried is to set the chmod for the data-folder to 777...

I get the following errors now:

```
C:\vayu_neu>mariadb\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=mariadb\my.ini --standalone --console
2017-09-21 15:16:06 12652 [Warning] 'THREAD_CONCURRENCY' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2017-09-21 15:16:06 12652 [Note] mariadb\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 10.2.8-MariaDB-log) starting as process 13924 ...
2017-09-21 15:16:06 12652 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-09-21 15:16:06 12652 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-09-21 15:16:06 12652 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-09-21 15:16:06 12652 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-09-21 15:16:06 12652 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2017-09-21 15:16:06 12652 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-09-21 15:16:06 12652 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-09-21 15:16:06 12652 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2017-09-21 15:16:06 12652 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2017-09-21 15:16:06 12652 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2017-09-21 15:16:06 12652 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2017-09-21 15:16:07 12652 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-09-21 15:16:07 12652 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-09-21 15:16:07 12652 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-09-21 15:16:07 12652 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2017-09-21 15:16:07 12652 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the permission for the user that runs the database of the directory specified by innodb_data_home_dir in the database configuration file (.ini), maybe it's a different directory

Comment: hi, the innodb_data_home_dir and the innodb_log_group_home_dir is exactly the same '/mariadb/data/'

Comment: also i set the chmod for the data-folder to 777.

Comment: there is no chmod on Windows, gnu tools do not handle Windows file security model which is based on ACLs, rather than simplistic user/group/others Unix access bits . You got errors because the user did not have write access to the files. Maybe user would have write access, if you started in elevated prompt, but now you would not know

Answer (score 0):

Modify or disable the SELINUX service if you have changed directories.
This does not allow the creation of files and the launch of MySQL after a DATA directory change.

Answer (score -3):

Deleting the files ibdata1, ibdata2, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 somehow seemed to solve the issue. I don't know why but it did.

Comment: Please never delete ibdata1 and ibdata2 if you have any data in database

Comment: Exactly, if you do, you won't be able to access the data again